# Does file sizes affect Wear Levelling in SSD?

Tags: ssd

Static wear levelling occurs in solid state drives for, iirc, keeping the cells healthy.

This thing struck me: does written file size affect the WL?

That is, will it be different (to the cells) by writing one 1GB file, ten 100MB files or 100 10MB files? Or is it an often occurent of writes, no matter the sizes, that wears the drive out? Or something else?

Comment: No; It does not.

Comment: Depending on the file system more files might affect it a bit more negatively because more changes to the data structures handling the file metadata (file name and such) need to be made and this might affect more cells in total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SSD (or harddisk) has no knowledge at all about the concept of 'files'.

When an operating system writes a file it splits it into blocks and only tells the SSD to write one block of information at a time at a certain address. The operating system does all the bookkeeping.

Large files or small files only impacts the amount of these blocks sent to the SSD